# decimal to long - always missing a dot separator

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to be able to convert a

```
varchar > decimal > long
```

when `dbreader[11]` holds a `3319419,13` as varchar

For example:

```
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(dbreader[11], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get

```
d = 3319419.13M
```

When i convert this to long object I end up with

```
long i = 3319419
```

I want to end up with **3319419,1**

Comment: A long is an 8 byte integer (whole number)

Comment: Not being a c# developer I might be wrong, but isn't long an integer data type? Do you expect the integer to hold a floating point number?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to display the number as text, i.e. "3319419,1", or round the number to one decimal place, i.e. 3319419.1?

Answer (score 6):

It never will, I'm afraid.  `long` is a synonym for `System.Int64` - a 64 bit integer value so it is unable to store the precision you are asking it to.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot end up with 3319419,1 in a `long`, because `long` is integer.
Try using a `double` instead.

**EDIT:** Now, `double` happens to be a floating-point number. This means that the number of decimal digits that this type is capable of representing is not fixed, but variable. So, if you want to see a specific number of decimal digits, then this is entirely a matter of display. So, in order to see your double variable with only one digit, convert it to string as follows: `String.Format( "{0:00.0}", my_double_variable );`

Answer (score 0):

A long is an 8 byte integer (whole number). If you require more precision, use a double (8 byte decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Reality check.

> 3319419,1

A long is incapable of keeping partial numbers. 1, 2, 3 - not 1, 1.1, 1.2. This is teh definition of a long.

SO, you CAN NOT keep fractional values in a long, regardless what you want. Want to keep fractional values - use a data type that can.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` does not have any decimals. It is an integer type.

You might want to use `double`, or keep it as a `decimal`.